# How to code jQuery more modularly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, model-view-controller, jinja2

I'm using a framework (Django) and I have a lot of flexibility in how I write HTML. I keep thinking that the way I'm writing jQuery could be better.

Take this for example: mostly anywhere a submit button appears on our site, we convert it into a prettier button (takes the original values and behavior and replaces it basically). This is just an example but there are a lot of use cases where I have snippets of html placed on the site and the overarching structure has no idea what is on the page that need to be manipulated by Javascript. So 2 part question: is it efficient to execute something on 100 pages that will only be used on 50 (jQuery plugin that searches for a wrapped set first), and if I wanted to just really have a modular approach with my jQuery, how would I go about it?

Comment: Maybe Backbone.js? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: Good question, I was just thinking about this yesterday and would like to see some suggestions

Comment: I would use jQuery plugins. Here is some boilerplate code you might find helpful. http://www.websanova.com/tutorials/jquery/jquery-plugin-development-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

If the fundamental concern in your question is about [Modular programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). I am currently studying  [Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts"](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/javascript-the-good-parts/).

From this book:

> Functions are the fundamental modular unit of JavaScript. They are
>   used for code reuse, information hiding, and composition.

So, as in javascript all functions are objects, you can use object literal notation to define top-level structures as modules in this way:

```
/* only one global variable to encapsulate all your code */

var MAINOBJ= {};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /* modules */

    MAINOBJ.formStuff = {
        results : [],
        myFunction: function (){
            // code
            results = MAINOBJ.ajaxStuff.loadResults();
            // code
        }
    }

    MAINOBJ.ajaxStuff = {
        results : [],
        loadResults: function (){
            // code
            return results;
        }
    }

    /* DOM traversing */

    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        MAINOBJ.formStuff.myFunction();
    });
})
```

Actually is my way to structure all my jquery code inside wordpress/joomla, etc., where we share the same scope with a lot of foreigner javascript code.

Comment: I'm not asking how to use an object literal to organize my code... I'm asking how to implement my code in small modular pieces which can be mixed & matched.

Comment: @xckpd7 Aha. Got it. Maybe [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw] (Nicholas Zakas Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture) is what you are looking for. There is a short tutorial in [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/writing-modular-javascript-new-premium-tutorial/ ] (Writing Modular JavaScript) based on this video.

Answer (score 0):

With proper caching, it is definitely more efficient to have a single minified .js file. It will only be loaded once and there will only be 1 call per page. If you modularize your code, you will end up doing more requests, while not saving any time dling the extra js, as it will be cached anyway.

Comment: If spreading the code over many files is your concern: multiple source files can be (and should be) concatenated into a single file and minified. But this is not something OP should worry about while programming, this is strictly a build time concern (or, a run-time concern, if you have a plugin which does this on the fly). Efficiency should not effect modularity in this case. **(Edit)** But I think I got you wrong first time: you are right, it is probably more efficient to fetch a single js file, than having this script load additional modules as needed (if that's what you meant).

Comment: Yeah but I have more than just that submit to worry about... I have validation for forms... I have widgets... I mean ideally I could just add some javascript in with the snippets (could I do that?) Would this be a job for something like pubsub? Would I just identify a script and call $(document).ready continuously (and just cache document ready)? Is that approach a little too segmented, and maybe I need a way to call stuff modularly but have a more focal all in one way of defining code?

Comment: @xckpd7 I can't answer that as it will ultimately depend on your situation. What problem are you trying to solve by modularizing your code?

Comment: messiness and un-maintanability...  I don't want to run everything all the time, and I don't want small pieces of Javascript strewn all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need : http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/explainer/index.html . But it is still very experimental. For now look at the google closure tools.